# Using ngPluralize within select

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to use ngPluralize inside of a select tag configured with ngOoptions to pluralize the options of the dropdown list?

I currently have the following controller

```
function Ctrl ($scope) {
  $scope.ranges = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  $scope.range = $scope.ranges[4];

  $scope.$watch('range', function(val) {
    console.log('change' + val);
  });
};
```

and the following markup

```
<div ng-controller="LiveViewerCtrl">
  <select ng-model="range" 
          ng-options="range for range in ranges" 
          ng-pluralize 
          count="range" 
          when="{'1': '1 Minute', 'other': '{} Minutes'}">
  </select>
</div>
```

I also tried to create the options myself using ng-repeat and that worked fine. Unfortunatly the dropdown list had an empty default value and was not preselected although I specified a default value in my controller. If I use the ngOptions approach the preselection works, but the values are not pluralized.

Comment: Nope, it's not going to fly. `ngPluralize` needed to be set on item with pluralizable text (read `<option>`), but it's defined onto `<select>`. The way out is to use `ngRepeat` instead of `ngOptions`
http://plnkr.co/edit/PcY7MVykf10w0AtueBJf

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As you and @Stewie mentioned, the ng-repeat approach seems to be correct. I just looked at your example and saw the ng-selected directive. This solved my problem with the pre selection perfectly. Thank you guys

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As [Dmitry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471736/using-ngpluralize-within-select#comment21897385_15471736) explained, `ngPluralize` cannot be used with `ngOptions`, but nothing stops you from using it with `ngRepeat`:

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="AppController">

  <select ng-model="selectedRange">
    <option value="">Select number ...</option>
    <option 
      ng-repeat="range in ranges"
      ng-pluralize
      count="range"
      when="{1: '{{range}} minute', other: '{{range}} minutes'}"
    >{{range}}</option>  
  </select>

</body>
```

JS:

```
app.controller('AppController',
    [
      '$scope',
      function($scope) {
        $scope.ranges = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
        $scope.selectedRange = $scope.ranges[4];
      }
    ]
  );
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CZ4xMfDHEmt4jgOlQlFY)

By the way, about your "pre-select" troubles, be aware that JavaScript arrays are [zero-indexed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Comment: The creation of the options with pluralization and ngRepeat works fine, but I still can't get the pre-selection working. In jsfiddle the pre-selection was the first entry instead of a blank default value but still not the value I set in the ngModel of the select tag. http://jsfiddle.net/7ZJ9P/

Comment: You can remedy that by using ng-selected next to ng-repeat: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MNBzG/).

Comment: Thank you again for that input I already found that in Dimitrys example.