# How can I use ng-pluralize within a loop and reference the count?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When using ng-pluralize within a loop how can I access the iterator in the count attribute?

```
<option ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4,5]" value="{{ i }}">
  {{ i }} star<ng-pluralize count="i" when="{'1': '', 'other': 's'}"></ng-pluralize>
</option>
```

This outputs:

- 1 star
- 2 star
- 3 star
- ...

Instead i want:

- 1 star
- 2 stars
- 3 stars
- ...

Comment: @PSL The question isn't an exact duplicate: the problem isn't really the same.

Comment: @Blackhole That answer exactly tells how to use it. If that answer has been followed probably this issue would not have happened? Basically it has a very generic subject as well?

Comment: @PSL I agree on the principle, really. But isn't the policy, here on Stack Overlow, to mark question as duplicate if the **question** is the same, not just the answer?

Comment: I have voted to reopen.. Especially because there are not too many of these in SO.. But a google search popped me right to the answer and documentation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [HTML `<option>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) can only accept text, not elements (and in particular, not a `<ng-pluralize>` element). Therefore, you should use the [`ngPluralize`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPluralize) directive directly on the `<option>` element:

```html
<option
    ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4,5]" value="{{ i }}"
    ng-pluralize
    count="i"
    when="{1: '1 star', 'other': '{} stars'}"
>
</option>
```

**Related question: [using ngPluralize within select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471736/using-ngpluralize-within-select).**

Comment: Thanks! That helps clear it up for me - it's a little confusing how that attribute sets the content within the tag.  @PSL must have superior googling skills, I couldn't find an example of ng-repeat and ng-pluralize working together in the docs or on SO.